# A mass falls to the ground from a height. What's the change of the entropy of the universe?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility

A mass $m$ falls to the ground from a height $h$. The temperature $T$ is constant. What's the change of the entropy of the universe?

It's an example in Carter's Classical and Statistical Thermodynamics. The book gives this answer:

*The process is irreversible but we can imagine the mass being slowly and reversibly lowered by a string and pulley arrangement. Since no heat exchange is involved, $\Delta S_\text{system} = 0$, but $$\Delta S_\text{universe} = \Delta S_\text{surroundings} = \frac{W_r}{T} = \frac{mgh}{T}.$$ We note that for the surroundings, which are unchanged if the mass is small, $$T\Delta S=Q_r=\Delta U+W_r=0+mgh.$$*

My question is about the surroundings. They do work on the system so $W_r=mgh$ seems plausible. But according to the first law of thermodynamics, the surroundings also absorb heat $Q_r=0+mgh=mgh$. I wonder where the heat comes from. Is it generated after $m$ falls to the ground and becomes stationary?
If this is so, then another question arises. Before $m$ touching the ground, what gives the surroundings heat to let them do work on $m$?

Comment: What are the surroundings of the universe?

Comment: I think the surroundings are the ground, the system is $m$. There are only these things in the universe of this question.

Comment: That's not the universe, but the environment of this system. It's important to make that distinction. If the mass falls on the ground, the temperature is not constant. Something will heat up locally. The entropy change will depend on that. You can make this fall entire reversible or entirely irreversible. Until you describe that properly, the entropy change is not defined.

Comment: I think in this question, the ground is regarded as a reservoir, whose temperature is constant throughout the process. But there is heat flows to the ground.

Comment: You can't have heat flow when the temperature is constant.

Comment: I see no problem in constant temperature of the ground. Its heat capacity is infinitely large so its temperature doesn't change.

Comment: There has to be a temperature difference for heat to flow.

Comment: I have some thought now. The kinetic energy of $m$ comes from the potential energy of $m$ + ground, which I think is a part of the internal energy of $m$ + ground as a whole. In most of the questions in thermodynamics(like gas in a piston), there's no need to consider the potential energy between systems and surroundings.

Comment: Of course the potential energy needs to be considered. That's the difference between an ideal gas and a non-ideal one. The problem here is that YOU have to specify if this is a reversible or an irreversible process. Your mass can hit a spring and bounce back or it can end up dead on the floor heating a piece of material that then releases its heat to the environment. Thermodynamics can't decide that for you.

Comment: There's still no potential energy between non-ideal gas and its surroundings. The potential energy is between the gas molecules and it's a part of the internal energy of the gas.

Comment: In the question $m$ is eventually stationary on the ground.

Comment: Even if it is stationary on the ground the process can be reversible. It could be a spring with an arrester mechanism. So does something get heated up and does heat flow or not?

Comment: I've typed all of the question. It doesn't specify those things. You have to think about what could happen.

Comment: That was my point. What that is usually supposed to mean is that something heats up and there is irreversible heat flow. What's the max. heat that can flow? What's the temperature? There is your answer.

Comment: I don't think this question is that complex. There's a mass, it falls on the ground from a height and eventually stationary on the ground. The temperature of $m$ will finally becomes $T$, the same as the ground since it's a reservoir.

Comment: You only have to know the initial and the final states to compute entropy change. You don't need to know what happens during this period.

Comment: Omg I want to chat with you but my reputation is too low. Sorry to anyone saw this mess. :P

Comment: The thermodynamics of the universe as a whole is highly problematic. See, e.g., Kragh, Helge. “[Pierre Duhem, Entropy, and Christian Faith](http://moerwiki.us.to/misc/Physics%20papers%20and%20books/Duhem/Pierre%20Duhem,%20Entropy,%20and%20Christian%20Faith%20(Helge%20Kragh):%20Duhem%20&%20Lema%c3%aetre.pdf).” _Physics in Perspective_ 10, no. 4 (December 1, 2008): 379–95. doi:[10.1007/s00016-007-0365-z](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00016-007-0365-z).

Comment: Isn't it simply a way to analyze the change in entropy by imagining a reversible way to reach the end state? When lowering the mass, the system does work $W_r$ on the surroundings. When dropping the mass, that same energy is converted into heat $Q_r$.

Answer (score 1):

The potential energy you list, $mgh$ is converted into kinetic energy. When the mass $m$ hits the ground, its kinetic energy is transferred into vibrations in the surroundings which become disorganized over time, eventually becoming random motions of small particles which we call heat or thermal energy. So, gravitational energy is ultimately converted to heat in this process, and this heat spreads through the surroundings. At the end of the day, there is heat transfer.

On the other hand, if you catch the mass with a spring and then stop the spring from rebounding, the gravitational potential energy is converted to spring potential energy, not to heat. If you released the spring, the mass would return to its initial height before falling again. Since this is perfectly reversible, there is no entropy change.

Answer (score -1):

Here. It is the case of entropy generation due to mechanical irreversibility.as change in entropy=dq/T + entropy generated
In irreversible cases.There is no heat interaction between body and surroundings.